# What determines the name QEMU will give a drive?

Tags: hard-drive, grub, qemu

I am playing around with GRUB 2 as a BIOS for QEMU. I expected that I could just use `hd0,msdos1` as the root for GRUB, but it looks like it is not that simple.

When I boot a VM with `qemu-system-x86_64 -bios grub.bin -hda disk.img`, the name of the device as it appears to GRUB is `ata0`. I did some searching online and came across [this](https://rubenerd.com/sata-on-qemu/) page after figuring it depended on what QEMU was treating `disk.img` as. So, I ran `qemu-system-x86_64 -bios grub.bin -drive file=disk.img,if=none,id=disk -device ich9-ahci,id=ahci,drive=disk,bus=ahci.0` and the disk's name appeared as `ahci0`.

How can I get it to appear as `hd0`, like it does when I run GRUB on a machine?

Answer (score 0):

Change `bus=ahci.0` to `bus=ide.0`.